# Which jQuery methods are available to use in the object argument of a jQuery create element call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, createelement

John Resig post at:
http://ejohn.org/apps/workshop/adv-talk/#3
says I can attach methods using the object parameter.

'text' seems to work just fine, but anything else in the object is added as an attribute to the element.

**Are there any other methods I can attach to this?**

```
$("<li/>", { 
  click: function(){}, 
  id: "test", // mix ids and jQuery methods 
  class: "clickable" 
});
```

**or is this the solution?**

```
$("<li/>")
  .click(function(){})
  .attr("id","test")
  .addClass("clickable");
```

Comment: Show an example page that you're using, including the jQuery version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking through the jQuery source, it looks like @Neal is *almost* right. It appears that using the syntax

```
$(htmlCode, config);
```

is equivalent to calling:

```
$(htmlCode).attr(config, true);
```

where `true` is an (undocumented?) parameter telling `.attr()` to call the jQuery functions named in the `config` keys IF they are listed in `$.attrFn`. The `$.attrFn` list (at least in jQuery 1.6.4) includes the following functions:

> val, css, html, text, data, width, height, offset, blur, focus, focusin, focusout, load, resize, scroll, unload, click, dblclick, mousedown, mouseup, mousemove, mouseover, mouseout, mouseenter, mouseleave, change, select, submit, keydown, keypress, keyup, error

So the `config` object can contain either keys representing attribute names, with their values (the default) or any of the function names listed above, with their first argument. I think Resig has a typo when he shows `addClass` as a key in his config object, because as you note, this just produces an attribute with the name "addclass".

Comment: This answers my original question quite nicely thank you. I think the question becomes, why use the config object if there is no performance advantage? There must be enough overlap in performance given the myriad use cases to warrant its existence though,... I would hope.

Comment: I think it's just an alternate syntax. One advantage is that you could assign the `config` object to a variable and reuse it for multiple selections.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("<li/>", {
      //any attribute can go here
      'id': 'text',
      'class': 'clickable'
   })
  .click(function(){})
```

Comment: More than just attributes can be attached to this element through this object, although there really isn't exhaustive documentation on that.
Specifically, there are some jQuery event bindings that can be done, as well as the 'text' method. Other methods as listed by @nrabinowitz are kind of a crap shoot.

Comment: @bodine -- as well as text and html.... both of which are technically attributes of the dom element

Comment: Good point. It was just an error of mine preventing this from working as expected

Answer (score 1):

I have just tested both methods. Both approaches produce the same result (HTML code, DOM properties), while the second option is twice as fast.

Testcase:

```
javascript:void(function(){
var t=new Date;
for(var i=0;i<100;i++){

/*paste code here, copy the whole code to the location bar*/

}
alert((new Date).getTime()-t.getTime())})();
```

Comment: Nice site, I will consider it when I perform more complex tests. I won't edit my answer for OP's ease of copy-pasting.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's clear given the simple performance advantage results that there doesn't seem to be much of a case to use the second parameter object to define the element.

As John Resig also points out, this can also be used for complex creation:

```
$("<li><a></a></li>") // li 
  .find("a") // a 
    .attr("href", "http://ejohn.org/") // a 
    .html("John Resig") // a 
  .end() // li 
  .appendTo("ul");
```

My assumption was that it would be slower this way, but I find this example to be more readable, as well as allowing for full jQuery method support instead of the subset mentioned by @nrabinowitz.